# Plist keeps being loaded and does not end, and it does not exit when conditions are met

Tags: python, macos, launchd

after losing so much hours trying to sort this problem out, I'm asking for help.

I've a Python Script working with Selenium which has to execute on my Mac every 24hrs. This is the plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>bot.subito</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python3.8</string>
        <string>/Users/someuser/somedir/bot.py</string>
    </array>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/someuser/somedir/errors/bot_subito.err</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/someuser/somedir/errors/bot_subito.out</string>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see, I've used the keywork `RunAtLoad` for running the code on startup and `KeepAlive` for not letting the process die. I could be wrong on how this thing works, though.
The problem is that with this setting, my code is executed but as soon as it finishes it starts again! Instead, I want it to run again after 24hrs or on startup. How can I sort this problem out?

Moreover, suppose that in this script it is present a snippet of code such as:

```py
def compare_24h_date(date1, date2):
  def compare_24h_date(date1, date2):
    # Suppose date2 > date1
    if date1[:4] == date2[:4]:
        if date1[5:7] == date2[5:7]:
            if date1[8:10] != date2[8:10]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    return True

if not compare_24h_date(timeOfPublishing, currTime):
    print("24 hours has not passed since last publish.\n")
    exit(0)
```

`compare_24hrs_date` takes 2 strings of `datetime.datetime.now()` and compare them too see equality. Since this function returns false in most cases, if condition should make my task end, wherease this does not happen. Is this related to impossibility to let task end with `exit(0)`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like `KeepAlive` is doing exactly what you are asking it to do, it's keeping your daemon alive, ignoring the fact that it successfully exited.

Try telling it explicitly, that it should leave the daemon to die on successful exits.

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
    <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I will try that ASAP! Thank you!